# How to bash into a docker container

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu

trying to bash into container and do a for loop which simply performs a command (which works on a single file by the way). it even seems to echo the right command...what did I forget
Untitled

```
for pdf in *.pdf ;
do 
 docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/home/docker" leofcardoso/pdf2pdfocr -g jpeg2000 -v -i '\'''$pdf''\''';
done
```

Comment: To bash into a container you need to run the image interactively `docker run -it <image> bash`. This will allow you to see and edit the content

Comment: Provided that the bash exists in the docker image ...

Comment: So i see that the base image used by leofcardoso/pdf2pdfocr is ubuntu 18.04 so bash should work

Comment: you can replace bash with any installed shell (`/bin/sh`). The post clearly states `How to bash...` I guess it is installed.

Comment: nope this won't work. the image has an ENTRYPOINT that forces every command to be passed as parameter to `/opt/install/docker-wrapper.sh`. Please check https://github.com/LeoFCardoso/pdf2pdfocr/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Have you tried `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <image> `

Answer (score 45):

You can bash in a container with this commands:

To see the docker container id

```
docker container ls
```

To enter in bash inside a container.

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
```

Comment: actually this doesn't work in this case. You should have an always running container in order to get inside it but this container is planned to be used as a fast executing container.

Answer (score 6):

First thing, you are not allocating `tty` in the docker run command and the docker container dies soon after [converting files](https://github.com/LeoFCardoso/pdf2pdfocr/blob/master/docker-wrapper.sh). Here is main process of container

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/docker
exec pdf2pdfocr.py "$@"
```

So, in this case, the life of this container is the life of `exec pdf2pdfocr.py "$@"` command.

As mentioned by @Fra, override the entrypoint and run the command manually.

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/home/docker" -it --entrypoint /bin/bash leofcardoso/pdf2pdfocr
```

but in the above run command, docker container will do not a thing and will just allocate the `tty` and the bash will open. So you can convert files inside your containers using docker exec and then run `pdf2pdfocr.py -g jpeg2000 -v -i mypdf.pdf`

So, if you want to run with override entry point then you can try.

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash -v "$(pwd):/home/docker" leofcardoso/pdf2pdfocr -c "pdf2pdfocr.py -g jpeg2000 -v -i mypdf.pdf"
```

or with the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
for pdf in *.pdf ;
do
 echo "converting $pdf" 
 docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash -v "$(pwd):/home/docker" leofcardoso/pdf2pdfocr -c "pdf2pdfocr.py -g jpeg2000 -v -i  $pdf"
done
```

But the container will die after completing the conversion.